# Decision Tree display isn't doing what I want

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to get a proper display of a Decision Tree; I am very close but I just can't get the display of the class correct.

When I use class_names=True, I get this:

[image]

## How do I interpret class=y[1]?

#### Here's more detail:

[image]

#### and

[image]

Note that the image is clipped, but it continues along the same lines.

#### Then:

```
clf.fit(X, Y)
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=combo.columns[2:], class_names=class_names)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data)
graph.render('r')
```

Which produces output like this, which I know is wrong, because the only grade which occurs 5 times is an A.

[image]

What is the problem?

#### Related links

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/decisiontreeclassifier-object-has-no-attribute-importances is an interesting answer with some useful tips but doesn't at all respond to the questions I have here.

Comment: What exactly is your context? Your shown `Y` implies a 9-class classification, while the `value` element in the shown tree nodes is for a 5-class one. What exactly is `y` - is it the same with the shown `Y`? Please include more details, sample data, and the exact code (no screenshots!) used for the visualizations - so far your question is quite unclear

Comment: What is shown as "y" (lowercase) is generated by the tree.export_graphviz. It's just coincidence and has nothing to do with my variable Y.. In other words the display always uses a lowercase y. ... OK I will try to restate the problem with code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=4)
clf.fit(X, Y)
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None, feature_names=Xprep.columns, class_names=clf.classes_)
```

It turns out that there is a slightly hard to find property on the result of the fit call: `clf.classes_` which contains the textual rendition of the classes.